# mysql-server-5.5 unmet dependencies each time running apt-get

Tags: ubuntu, apt, mysql

Each time I run "sudo apt-get install package-name", the following error happened, even if I tried to install other packages other than mysql ones:

```
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 mysql-server-5.5 : Depends: mysql-server-core-5.5 (= 5.5.44-0ubuntu0.12.04.1) but 5.5.46-0ubuntu0.12.04.2 is to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

For example:
When I downloaded mysql-5.5.44 and tried to install it by running "cmake .", it told me that cmake is not installed. When I run "sudo apt-get install cmake", the below error happened.

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 cmake : Depends: libxmlrpc-core-c3 but it is not going to be installed
         Depends: cmake-data (= 2.8.7-0ubuntu5) but it is not going to be installed
 mysql-server-5.5 : Depends: mysql-server-core-5.5 (= 5.5.44-0ubuntu0.12.04.1) but 5.5.46-0ubuntu0.12.04.2 is to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

**UPDATE**

Found lots of similar question on this site, but still stuck in the problem.
My source.list:

```
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS _Precise Pangolin_ - Release amd64 (20130213)]/ dists/precise/main/binary-i386/

# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS _Precise Pangolin_ - Release amd64 (20130213)]/ dists/precise/restricted/binary-i386/
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS _Precise Pangolin_ - Release amd64 (20130213)]/ precise main restricted

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise main restricted
deb-src http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates main restricted
deb-src http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise universe
deb-src http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise universe
deb http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates universe
deb-src http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise multiverse
deb-src http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise multiverse
deb http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates multiverse
deb-src http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security main restricted
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security universe
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security multiverse
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu precise partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu precise partner

## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by third-party
## developers who want to ship their latest software.
deb http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise main
deb-src http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise main
deb http://ubunturepo.internal/orgname precise/devgroup/devel main
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ precise partner
deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ precise partner
```

Output of running: apt-cache policy cmake libxmlrpc-core-c3 cmake-data mysql-server-5.5 mysql-server-core-5.5

```
cmake:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 2.8.7-0ubuntu5
  Version table:
     2.8.7-0ubuntu5 0
        500 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main amd64 Packages
     2.8.7-0ubuntu4 0
        500 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/main amd64 Packages
libxmlrpc-core-c3:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1.16.33-3.1ubuntu5.1
  Version table:
     1.16.33-3.1ubuntu5.1 0
        500 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-security/main amd64 Packages
     1.16.33-3.1ubuntu5 0
        500 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/main amd64 Packages
cmake-data:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 2.8.7-0ubuntu5
  Version table:
     2.8.7-0ubuntu5 0
        500 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main amd64 Packages
     2.8.7-0ubuntu4 0
        500 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/main amd64 Packages
mysql-server-5.5:
  Installed: 5.5.44-0ubuntu0.12.04.1
  Candidate: 5.5.46-0ubuntu0.12.04.2
  Version table:
     5.5.46-0ubuntu0.12.04.2 0
        500 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-security/main amd64 Packages
 *** 5.5.44-0ubuntu0.12.04.1 0
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     5.5.22-0ubuntu1 0
        500 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/main amd64 Packages
mysql-server-core-5.5:
  Installed: 5.5.46-0ubuntu0.12.04.2
  Candidate: 5.5.46-0ubuntu0.12.04.2
  Version table:
 *** 5.5.46-0ubuntu0.12.04.2 0
        500 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-security/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     5.5.22-0ubuntu1 0
        500 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/main amd64 Packages
```

**UPDATE**
I added the following to source.list:

```
deb http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main amd64 Packages
deb-src http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main amd64 Packages
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-security/main amd64 Packages
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-security/main amd64 Packages
```

Then, runn apt-get update. The error is:

```
W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-security/main/amd64/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-security/main/Packages/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-security/main/amd64/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-security/main/Packages/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-security/main/amd64/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-security/main/Packages/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-updates/main/amd64/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.14 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-updates/main/Packages/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.14 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-updates/main/amd64/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.14 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-updates/main/Packages/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.14 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-updates/main/amd64/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.14 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-updates/main/Packages/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.14 80]

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Comment: `cmake` to install MySQL? Probably not. [Edit] your question and add the output of `apt-cache policy cmake libxmlrpc-core-c3  cmake-data mysql-server-5.5  mysql-server-core-5.5`

Comment: @A.B. post already updated. Because it complains that one package is missing. so I downloaded the source code and tried to cmake it and install it.

Comment: First run `sudo apt-get install mysql-server-5.5=5.5.46-0ubuntu0.12.04.2` and give me the output.

Comment: Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 mysql-server-5.5 : Breaks: mysql-server (< 5.5.46-0ubuntu0.12.04.2) but 5.5.44-0ubuntu0.12.04.1 is to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).

Comment: Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 cmake-data : Depends: emacsen-common but it is not going to be installed
 mysql-server-5.5 : Depends: mysql-server-core-5.5 (= 5.5.44-0ubuntu0.12.04.1) but 5.5.46-0ubuntu0.12.04.2 is to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).

Comment: The output of `apt-cache policy mysql-server`

Comment: mysql-server:
  Installed: 5.5.44-0ubuntu0.12.04.1
  Candidate: 5.5.46-0ubuntu0.12.04.2
  Version table:
     5.5.46-0ubuntu0.12.04.2 0
        500 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-security/main amd64 Packages
 *** 5.5.44-0ubuntu0.12.04.1 0
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     5.5.22-0ubuntu1 0
        500 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/main amd64 Packages

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32427/discussion-between-chengcheng-pei-and-a-b).

Comment: `sudo apt-get install mysql-server=5.5.46-0ubuntu0.12.04.2`

Comment: Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 mysql-server-5.5 : Depends: mysql-server-core-5.5 (= 5.5.44-0ubuntu0.12.04.1) but 5.5.46-0ubuntu0.12.04.2 is to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually the first step is:

```
 sudo apt-get install mysql-server=5.5.46-0ubuntu0.12.04.2 mysql-server-5.5=5.5.46-0ubuntu0.12.04.2
```

But not in your case, therefore

```
apt-get download mysql-server mysql-server-5.5
sudo dpkg -i --force-all mysql-server*.deb
```